# Need to create div shape as in the example

Tags: css

Hello stackoverflow people, I need help. Do you guys know how to edit shape of div? I need to create something like `div 1` and cut the div 2 part:
[image]

Is it even possible? Maby you guys can help me to do such a thing? Because I've got no idea!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible.
Skew the top blok 5 degrees and give it a border-bottom. Skew the content of the top block -5 degrees to make sure it's straight again.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top">
        <aside class="skew-outer">
            <div class="skew-inner">
                Top content
            </div>
        </aside>
    </div>
     <div class="bottom">
         bottom content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    border: solid red 1px;
}
.bottom {
    padding: 20px;
}
.skew-outer {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(5deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(5deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(5deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(5deg);
    transform: skewY(5deg);
    border-bottom: solid red 1px;
    padding: 30px;
}

.skew-inner {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-5deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(-5deg);
    transform: skewY(-5deg);
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnpfcyoL/1/)**